# Rendering CALayer multiple times

Tags: macos, core-animation

I've been trying to figure out the best way to show an existing CALayer in a secondary window to allow real-time full-screen output on a secondary monitor. Additionally I would like to have the ability to show real-time thumbnails in my application of the original CALayer, it seems like I should be able to find a setup that could fulfill both requirements.

So far my research resulted in the following options:

1. **CALayer.render(in: CGContext)** Using the original layer and redrawing it to additional views this way and setting up a timer or a CVDisplayLink to redraw it every frame.
2. **Rendering the CALayer to a NSBitmap every frame.** And using that bitmap in NSImageView across the application.
3. **Using a CAMetalLayer and rendering the texture multiple times using a MTKView.** I'm not really familiar with Metal, this seems like a fairly elegant solution, but I'm not sure if it is required to go all the way down to Metal myself.
4. **Using a CARemoteLayerServer with a CARemoteLayerServer.**
   This seems like an overly complicated setup for in-process sharing of a CALayer and it feels like this approach is more suitable if I'd need to share the layer cross-process.
5. **Using CAReplicatorLayer.** Instead of using the replicator layer to create a grid of copies I tried to use it to create just one copy, but it seems like you cant add a CALayer to multiple "parent layers".

All in all I've found some workable solutions, but as I'm quite a novice working with Core Animation I'm not sure which direction is the least resource-heavy and I might still be missing an easier solution.

Has anyone tried something similar?

Comment: You can provide the same object as the `contents` of multiple layers. `CALayer` accepts `CGImage`, `NSImage`, and (not well documented) `IOSurfaceRef` for `contents`.

Comment: It seems `contents` will stay empty when just drawing simple shapes? The only working option I've got so far is calling `render(in: customContext)` and using `duplicateLayer.contents = customContext.makeImage()` but performance wise that's not ideal. I'll try using a child window and using the `IOSurfaceRef` of that window next, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't suggesting that you obtain the contents of a drawn layer. I was suggesting you do your original drawing into an image or IOSurface and then set it as the contents for all of the layers. By the way, there's no such thing as "the `IOSurfaceRef` of [a] window", at least not publicly. You have to create IOSurfaces or IOSurface-backed textures or images explicitly.